# Python: multiple files download by turn

Tags: python

In script loop performs files downloading and saving (curl). But loop iterations too quick, so downloading and saving actions have no time to complete it's operations. Thereat result files comes broken

```
def get_images_thread(table):
    class LoopThread ( threading.Thread ):
        def run ( self ):
            global db
            c=db.cursor()
            c.execute(""" SELECT * FROM js_stones ORDER BY stone_id LIMIT 1
                            """)           
            ec = EasyCurl(table)

            while(1):
                stone = c.fetchone()
                if stone == None:
                    break
                img_fname = stone[2]
                print img_fname
                url = "http://www.jstone.it/"+img_fname
                fname = url.strip("/").split("/")[-1].strip()
                ec.perform(url, filename="D:\\Var\\Python\\Jstone\\downloadeble_pictures\\"+fname, 
                                    progress=ec.textprogress)
```

Comment: What do you mean by '(curl)'? Are you using python bindings - PyCURL, or command line utility? It would help if you posted some of your code.

Comment: here problem section of my code

Comment: You haven't posted the code which actually does the download, so there's no way to give a useful answer. You imply the download happens asynchronously, so what you need to do is to ensure you only start a limited number of downloads at a time and then wait until they complete before starting another. Use a Queue for that: write URLs into the queue and have a limited number of threads reading them and fetching the data. Use another Queue to indicate back to the main thread when complete.

Comment: Queue! Here the answer! Thnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an excerpt from the [examples for the PycURL library](http://pycurl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pycurl/pycurl/examples/retriever.py?view=markup),

```
# Make a queue with (url, filename) tuples
queue = Queue.Queue()
for url in urls:
    url = url.strip()
    if not url or url[0] == "#":
        continue
    filename = "doc_%03d.dat" % (len(queue.queue) + 1)
    queue.put((url, filename))


# Check args
assert queue.queue, "no URLs given"
num_urls = len(queue.queue)
num_conn = min(num_conn, num_urls)
assert 1 <= num_conn <= 10000, "invalid number of concurrent connections"
print "PycURL %s (compiled against 0x%x)" % (pycurl.version, pycurl.COMPILE_LIBCURL_VERSION_NUM)
print "----- Getting", num_urls, "URLs using", num_conn, "connections -----"


class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            try:
                url, filename = self.queue.get_nowait()
            except Queue.Empty:
                raise SystemExit
            fp = open(filename, "wb")
            curl = pycurl.Curl()
            curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
            curl.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
            curl.setopt(pycurl.MAXREDIRS, 5)
            curl.setopt(pycurl.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30)
            curl.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, 300)
            curl.setopt(pycurl.NOSIGNAL, 1)
            curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEDATA, fp)
            try:
                curl.perform()
            except:
                import traceback
                traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)
                sys.stderr.flush()
            curl.close()
            fp.close()
            sys.stdout.write(".")
            sys.stdout.flush()


# Start a bunch of threads
threads = []
for dummy in range(num_conn):
    t = WorkerThread(queue)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)


# Wait for all threads to finish
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Comment: Queue, yes. Thts what I need, Thnx

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking what I think you're asking,

```
from time import sleep
sleep(1)
```

should "solve"(It's hacky to the max!) your problem. Docs [here](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/time.html#time.sleep). I would check that that really is your problem, though. It seems catastrophically unlikely that pausing for a few seconds would stop files from downloading brokenly. Some more detail would be nice too.

```
os.waitpid()
```

might also help.

Comment: yes, sleep(1) or sleep(20) or sleep(60) - it's the solution, but I want more optimize way to start next iteration exactly when system is ready to process next file

Comment: This is not the right answer at all. You have to use concurrency techniques to do this correctly.